# Exception:Unknown Property under LINUX, but not under Windows using kartik widget CheckBoxX

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, kartik-v

following code will throw out Exception like this using LINUX. Using Windows, everything is all right, but code will be hosted under LINUX, so it can't be hosted, actually. 
Exception:

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
Setting unknown property: kartik\checkbox\CheckboxX::autoLabel
```

Code, which will run under Windows, but not under LINUX:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <?=$form->field($model, 'veroeffentlichen_bewerberboerse')->widget(\kartik\checkbox\CheckboxX::classname(), ['autoLabel' => true])->label(false);
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it by my own. I had to change package information in json and to update framework using composer.